# NGXS and compatibility with angular 9

Tags: ngxs, angular9

I must upgrade my old application running in angular 6 to new version angular 9.

I used NGXS for my application.

Is NGXS compatible with Angular 9?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, NGXS is compatible with Angular 9 (and Ivy).

You'll need to check the version of NGXS you are running against the change log (suggest you move to at least v3.6.0)

https://github.com/ngxs/store/blob/master/CHANGELOG.md#breaking-changes-1